# Drag & Drop label text Vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop

Hello all: iam using WPF to create some controls, right now iam just testing with a simple control that consist in a Rectangle and a Stack Panel with Two labels in it.
I followed the Drag and Drop Operation sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144799.aspx which allows to drag the control to obtain its information (Color) and drop it to another one.
I want to do the same, but in this time instead of droping the color i want to drop the text of the label.
For example in the first control i have two labels: is "Channel" and "Type", so i want that with the D&D replace the labels from second control to change its info to " Channel x" or "type x"

First Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BxCtrl"
             .......
             .....
             AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid Width="150" Height="150">

<Rectangle x:Name="Box" Fill="gray" MouseMove="Box_MouseMove" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Grid.Row="0" />
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Channel" Width="auto" Height="28.093" Margin="25,15,67.133,15" Name="label"/>
            <Label Content="Type" Width="42.933" Height="28.093" Margin="25,20,0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label1"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

and a second one exactly the same

```
<UserControl
...
...
x:Class BxCtrl1
AllowDrop="True"
<Grid Width="150" Height="150">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Box1" Fill="#FFCABFD5" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" MouseMove="Box1_MouseMove" Tag="hoola" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Name="StackPanel1">
            <Label Content="1" Width="auto" Height="28.093" Margin="25,15,67.133,15" Name="labelBox1"/>
            <Label Content="1" Width="42.933" Height="28.093" Margin="25,20,0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="label1Box1"/>
        </StackPanel>                       
    </Grid>
```

according to the document for the drag and drop operation i have to create the objects i want to send with a dataObject so i suppose that i have to create a dataObject for the label?

```
Private Sub Box_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)
    'TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        Dim data As New DataObject
        data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, Box.Fill.ToString())
        data.SetData("Double", Box.Height)
        data.SetData("Object", Me)
        data.GetText()

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(Me, data, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If
End Sub
```

i use the GetText(), but i dont know how to send it, anyone has idea of how to drop a label text into another one?.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is stuff your information in the DataObject so it can be reteived later when you handle the drop even in the other control.  Read on in the tutorial and you will see they implement a "OnDrop" event and the key here is that the data you suffed in there comes out in

```
byval e As System.Windows.DragEventArgs
...
Dim dataString As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat)
```

Comment: yes on the "onDrop" i have:
`if e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat) Then
Dim dataString as String= e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat)
..more code
End If
e.handled=true
end sub`

but i dont know how to pass or recieve the label information, i need to instanciate what or how to do it?

Comment: (In the mousemove) data.SetData("Label1_Content", label1.content)  (and in the OnDrop)  ? = e.Data.GetData("Label1_Content")